# How to Compute time via DataTable footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to compute time in DataTable footer but all I have is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/redelramosredel/kdjv8o3q/4/)

```
"footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
    var api = this.api(),
      data;
    var intVal = function(i) {
      return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
    };

    totalhrs = api.column(3).data().reduce(function(a, b) {
      return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
    }, 0);
    totalhrs_page = api.column(3, {
      page: 'current'
    }).data().reduce(function(a, b) {
      return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
    }, 0);
    // Update footer
    $('#totalHours').html("<b>" + "TOTAL Hours: " + totalhrs_page + "/" + totalhrs + "</b>");
  }
```

As you can see in the demo, I'm getting the SUM of all the rows in the Hours Spent Column, what I need is to compute it for time. When the decimal place became >= 60 then it should +1 the whole number. Say the result is 23.82, it should be 24.22. Right now it only +1 the whole number when the decimal place reaches a hundred.

Is there an easier way to do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it to minutes in reduce function

```
  totalhrs = api.column(3).data().reduce(function(a, b) {
        b = b.split(".");
        var hours = b[0]||0;
        var min = b[1]||0;    
        return a + intVal(hours*60)+intVal(min);
        }, 0);
        totalhrs  = Math.floor(totalhrs  / 60)+"." + totalhrs % 60;
```

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/redelramosredel/kdjv8o3q/7/ it doesnt seem to compute nicely, it has .37 instead of .22. Why is that, Am I missing something ?

Comment: totalhrs  = Math.floor(totalhrs  / 60)+"." + totalhrs % 60;

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a little while ago:

```
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register('sumDuration()', function() {
    return this.flatten().reduce(function(a, b) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        if (typeof a === 'string') {
            a = moment.duration(a, "HH:mm").asSeconds();
        }
        if (typeof b === 'string') {
            b = moment.duration(b, "HH:mm").asSeconds();
        }
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
});
```

It uses MomentJS and another plugin to display the total duration correctly, there's a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/xw9yyLqf/).

Comment: Thanks. but I dont need the time conversion into HH:mm sir, I need to compute it and still return in decimal value